# Parsing an xml document at a remote URL using VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, msxml

I am trying to parse through the contents of an xml file resident on a remote server in visual basic 6.0 using the `MSXML2.DOMDocument` class.

I am using the `Load` method of the `MSXML2.DOMDocument` class to pass in the url. The url is of the form `http://<server>/ABC.xml`, however, the server requires user credentials for accessing the file.

How do I pass in user credentials using this class or another supporting class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `http://<username>:<password>@<server>/ABC.xml` in many cases, or you can use the `XMLHTTPRequest` helper object to make the actual requests.

Note that when you use an MSXML DOMDocument object you aren't parsing anything, the object does the heavy lifting.  All you're doing is navigating the DOM tree, a trivial task by comparison.